# Как добавить связь к новой записи в Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Нужно создать материал и заполнить теги для него (связь `многие ко многим`). Идентификаторы тегов хранятся в массиве `$tags`. Как правильно создать теги? Так работать, конечно, не хочет:

```
$material->tags()->saveMany($tags);
```

Через `new Tag()` создавать теги, думаю, неправильно, так как нужно добавить не тег, а связь id тега с материалом.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, ваши теги уже заранее созданы и у вас есть три таблицы. Например: materials, tags, tag_material

В моделе материала у вас настроены отношения:

```
public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'tag_material', 'material_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

*Последние три параметра необязательны, они нужны для явного определения*

Если теги заранее созданы и переменная $tags содержит массив с ID тегов, тогда можно сделать так:

```
$material->tags()->sync($tags);
```

Таким образом старые записи о тегах для этого материала будут перезаписаны, если их нет тогда будут просто добавлены.